# Не получается заполнить двумерный массив с помощью for

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, for

```
c = 3
st = [[0,0]]*c
for i in range (0,c ):
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    st[i][0] = a
    st[i][1] = b
print(st)
```

Данный код при вводе например

3
1
2
0
0
4
выводит `[[0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4]]`, а не ожидаемое мной `[[3, 1], [2, 0], [0, 4]]`.
Вопрос наверное глупый, но я не понимаю - почему так? i же не успевает проскочить и обновить все элементы массива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

почему не сделать это вот так?

```py
array = []
size = int(input('size'))
for i in range(size):
    buff = []
    for j in range(2):
        value = int(input('value'))
        buff.append(value)
    array.append(buff)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, это и правда, отлично работает!

Comment: Тем не менее, хочется понять, в чем именно проблема "моего" кода, такое чувство, что это что-то предельно очевидное, там не менее - ответа, в чем ошибка, нет)) Разобраться охота тоже

Comment: @ssgg это от того, что у вас массив - это список копий одного и того же объекта. в питоне списки - изменяемые, т.е изменяя его в одном месте - он меняется во всех. и т.к у вас это все один список, то последние изменения `0, 4` применяются ко всем эллементам

Comment: @ssgg по этому лучше создавать двумерные массивы на ходу, а не как вы. если решение вам помогло - поставьте галочку

Comment: Большое спасибо, не знал про изменяемость!

Answer (score 0):

```
c = 3
st = []

for i in range(c):
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    st.extend([[a, b]])
    
print(st)
```

Ваш цикл перезаписывает элементы вложенного списка каждый раз

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы при инициализации получались разные списки, а не копии одного и того же списка (как в вашем случае), её обычно делают так:

```py
st = [[0,0] for _ in range(c)]
```

`_` здесь - конвенциональное название переменной, которая синтаксически нужна в коде, но её значение нигде не используется.